# Adding a Function to a button

Tags: visual-c++

I am a beginner in visual cpp. i want to add functionility to a button. i want to show some text on the listbox on just clicking a button. So anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What GUI framework you are using? MFC, native WinApi, .NET, QT, WX ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating UI with Visual Studio GUI editor you can only add button to dialog and double click on this button. All of needed code will be created.
In another case, if you are creating custom dialog without UI editor you can add following code to your's dialog class(CMFCDlg inherits from CDialogEx):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCDlg, CDialogEx)
//...
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MYBUTTONID, &CMFCDlg::OnClickedMyButton)
//...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Where `IDC_MYBUTTONID` is an identifier of your button in resources and `CMFCDlg::OnClickedMyButton` is a function called in case of button clicked.